# Establishing the crime of rape in islamic law

Tags: sharia

How do islamic judicial system establishing that the crime of rape happened. Is the crime assumed to have taken place only on the word of mouth of the woman I read that the word of mouth is taken as evidence so is a innocent man hanged because some random woman with a vendetta said that she is raped by this man. If even a vaginal bleeding is taken as evidence in case of virgin woman it is completely possible that evil woman just shove her vagina with something to build a case and have a innocent man hanged. And even if pregnency is taken as evidence what if that child is from his husband and husband and wife collude to have that man hanged.How a man innocent man prove his innocence.and also Can he take Quranic oath as a last resort.will he be accquited.Otherwise I am seeing a innocent man being hanged which is a grave injustice. Please somebody shed light on this I am so confused right now.

Comment: I don't think this question properly address the question i am raising.My question is about proof of rape and how islamic law identify fake rape cases.How do a accused prove his innocence under these circumstances

Comment: The first part of the answer covers it. Punishing a person always requires proof, a mere accusation is not enough. The established forms of proof are confession or witnesses.

Comment: Can fake witnesses not be presented. Is accused allowed to produce counter witnesses. What if he can't produce a counter witnesses. How is it make sure that a innocent not be punished.

Comment: Obviously the witnesses and their testimony is vetted. What you are asking is different and more generic than your question in your post.